# class not registered (exception from hresult: 0x80040154(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: visual-studio

First time posting and I wouldn't be doing this if I didn't need to but I seem to have hit a brick wall with an error message I am getting when running my VB2012 Application.

To debug I printed the error into a Message Box.

The error is (Which I'm sure you have all seen before):

```
class not registered (exception from hresult: 0x80040154(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
```

I have done my research and I know all about changing the CPU target to x86, this has worked in the past when I have en-counted this error before.

For some background information the Application is built in Visual Studio 2012 (Previously 2005). The Application, lets call it helloworld.exe, is to be ran on Windows Server 2008. I can run this on my Laptop fine with no issue so I am wondering if Windows Server 2008 is missing something my laptop isn't or the other way around.

First time running a VB application on a Server so I don't know if they will work at all.

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see where it looks, and doesn't find, the registry key.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have loaded it and will be testing it today. I guess the errors will be easy to see as it will say COULD NOT FIND for example

Comment: NO NAME FOUND. Do I either set a path to it or remove from the path somehow?